# get the id of all connected devices on my network

Tags: python, performance, monitoring, scapy, traffic

I am trying to get the IP of all the connected devices on my network using python code, but I only get the IP of my device and of the router.
why is this happening while I suppose to get the IP of all the live devices on the specified range??
here is the code I am using
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your device and your router are the only two things on your local Ethernet network. Everything else is on a *different* network; your router is a gateway that allows traffic to pass between the two networks.

Comment: other devices has the same first three octet 192.168.0, how can I get their IPs since they are using the same network I am using

Comment: IP is an *internetwork* protocol. `broadcast` is only operating with the Ethernet network that makes up one portion of your wider local internet.  I'm not that familiar with Scapy, but I think you want `scapy.IP`, not `scapy.Ether`.

Comment: In a typical home setup, you probably have a wireless access point that access as a router between numerous point-to-point connects: each connection between the router and a wireless client is a different network, but the devices can communicate with each other via IP.